# Erro Swift_TransportException ao enviar e-amil usando SMTP + Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, swiftmailer, sendmail

Fala Pessoa, mais uma encrenca, é o seguinte:

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail através da minha aplicação (api), onde desenvolvo com Laravel 5.4. A coisa parece muito fácil, só que não!

Meu arquivo .env está da seguinte maneira:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.estilosoft.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=contato@estilosoft.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=meAjuda123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

*Incluse a senha é essa mesma, para vocês testarem e ver que não estou passando as informações erradas*

Eu tenho um model que se chama Contato, nele eu tenho a function *email()* a seguinte forma:

```
public function email($dados){

    Mail::send('contatoEmail',$dados, function ($message){
        $message->subject('E-Mail Example');
        $message->from('contato@estilosoft.com','Contato');
        $message->to('financeiro@estilosoft.com');
    });
    if(Mail::failures())
        return Mail::failures();
    else
    return true;
}
```

Também tenho um ContatoController, que faz a chamada na função:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Contato;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ContatoController extends Controller{

public function store(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nome' => 'required',
        'sobrenome' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'telefone' => 'required',
        'assunto' => 'required',
        'departamento_id'=> 'required',
        'mensagem' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['erro'=> true, 'mensagem'=>'Formato de dados inválidos!','data'=>$request->all()], 401);
    }

    $contato = new Contato();
    $contato->fill($request->all());
    if($contato->save()){
        if($contato->email($request->all())){
            return response()->json(['erro'=> false, 'mensagem'=>'Mensagem salva, email enviado!','data'=>$contato], 201);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['erro'=> false, 'mensagem'=>'Mensagem salva!','data'=>$contato], 201);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['erro'=> true, 'mensagem'=>'Não conseguimos salvar sua solicitação','data'=>$contato], 201);
    }
}

} // class
```

E para finalizar o problema, ou melhor, para darmos início ao problema, o maldito erro, que acontece ao tentar enviar o email:
[image: Erro que é apresentado no momento do envio]

Acho que não seja relevante postar algo referente a view, mas se for preciso posso postar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vezes a preguiça de não ler a documentação atrapalha bastante:

> Driver Prerequisites /-/
>   The API based drivers such as Mailgun and SparkPost are often simpler and faster than SMTP servers. If possible, you should use one of these drivers. All of the API drivers require the Guzzle HTTP library, which may be installed via the Composer package manager:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Com isso o problema foi resolvido, estava tentando enviar o email sem ter os pré-requisitos.

Fonte: [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#configuring-the-sender)